# Target Blank not opening the link in a new tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this in my HAML:

```
%a.btn.btn-primary.personlistbtn{href:patients_path, :target => "_blank"} Patients List
```

And it has generated this in HTML form when I do an Inspect Element on it:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary personlistbtn" href="/patients" target="_blank">Patients List</a>
```

But when I click on it, it just goes to the link, it doesn't open it in a new Tab.

Is it something I am doing wrong?

Note: In JavaScript OnClick event of this button I have a code like this, Is it the culprit:

```
 window.location.assign("http://localhost:3000/patients?provider="+provider_id+"&"+"therapeutic_class="+thera_class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your javascript looks to be the culprit.  So instead of `window.location.assign`, try using `window.open` as follows:

```
window.open("http://localhost:3000/patients?provider="+provider_id+"&"+"therapeutic_class="+thera_class, '_blank');
```